# Queue dequeue suggested way to free item

Tags: c

Let's say I have a queue ADT and I'd like to write a `dequeue` function.

```
typedef struct queue {
    Node*   front;
    Node*   rear;
    size_t  items;
} Queue;
```

What would be the proper way to `free` the `Node*` item in a dequeue? For example, if I did something along the lines of:

```
Node* dequeue(Queue* pq) {
    //
}
```

Then I could not `free` anything within the function call because I need to pass back a pointer to the `Node`. That seems like it would be a bit tedious/onerous for someone using this interface to have to `free` the objects from their end.

I suppose another way to do it would be to pass back a copy of the object via:

```
Node dequeue(Queue* pq) {...}
```

Or a third approach would be:

```
// user passes a `Node*` item and we write it back to item there
bool dequeue(Queue* pq, Node *item) {...}
```

Is there one approach that is suggested over the others? Why?

Comment: How was the data added to the queue in the first place? Are the nodes created by the user, or do they just pass the data values? For performance reasons, pass the node pointer, after ensuring it doesn't point back into your queue, but for good hygiene, make a copy, or better yet, have your callers provide pointers to output variables. In other words, pass the values back, not the nodes.

Comment: @jwdonahue thanks, would you want to show an example?

Comment: I could, if I had more information. There's no single answer to your question. It would require an entire chapter in a good data structures and algorithms book, to even give it brief coverage. That's why these kinds of questions aren't good for SO.

Comment: 'bit tedious/onerous for someone using this interface to have to free the objects from their end', maybe, but it's common and expected by C developers.

Comment: @jwdonahue 'for good hygiene, make a copy, or better yet, have your callers provide pointers to output variables. In other words, pass the values back, not the nodes' well, neither work well if the values are, say,  large network buffers.  If you make copies, (apart from overhead issue), the copy lifetime now has to be dealt with too, plus you now have the same data in two places - not good for integrity - even if only for a short time.

Comment: ..plus it's one less thing to test and worry about:  "What about the data size, do we need to check if large buffers affect latency too much?  The risk is a complete redesign if the app fails on performance at system integration"....."Nah, the queues are all O(1)"

Comment: @MartinJames, as I said, insufficient detail to provide a specific answer. Comments aren't a good place for this kind of topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your node struct points to the previous and following nodes and holds a single value which the queue is meant to hold right? In that case, don't return the node at all. Just return a copy of the value held by the node. So you'd have a Node that looked something like this:

```
typedef struct node {
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;
    int value;
} Node;
```

Then you'd have:

```
void enqueue(Queue* pq, int);
int dequeue(Queue* pq);
```

And the nodes themselves could be freed at the end of the dequeue() call after the relevant value has been copied. If your nodes hold malloc'd data, you'd store a pointer to that in the node instead of a copy of the data, but this would be fine since the programmer using your queue would have to malloc that space before passing a pointer to your enqueue(), and thus would also be on the hook for freeing that data themselves.

Comment: An optimization involves pruning the node you just popped and sticking it in an unused pool for later use. That way you don't frag your heap.

Comment: Why/when is this approach better than returning the node? I think this post doesn't quite answer the OP's two questions.

Comment: 'And the nodes themselves could be freed later' that is very bad for data integrity, especially with multithreaded apps where a lock is placed around the access - the dequeue must be fast and safe, eg. lock, remove pointer, unlock, return pointer to caller.

Comment: @jwdonahue pooling objects is much better, but I would argue that the repooling should be done by the caller after it has done with the object.